# Is it possible to convert a selective secure broadcast encryption scheme to an adaptive secure broadcast encryption scheme?

Tags: provable-security, broadcast-encryption, traitor-tracing

I was reading the paper, entitled ["Multiparty Key Exchange, Efficient Traitor Tracing, and More from
Indistinguishability Obfuscation", by Boneh et al.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/642) On page 23, the authors have claimed the following.

"Remark 6.2. We note that for private linear broadcast, there are only a polynomial number of
recipient sets, meaning selective and adaptive security are equivalent."

How can we prove this Remark? Is it possible to transform a selective secure private linear broadcast encryption scheme to an adaptive secure scheme (for the system which can accommodate at most a polynomial number of users)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a generic reduction from breaking selective security of a protocol $\mathsf{P}$ to breaking its adaptive security: the adaptive reduction for $\mathsf{P}$ simply guesses (at random) the information $w$ (in your case, the recipient set) that the adversary commits to in the selective experiment. Therefore, if $w$ comes from a universe $\mathcal{W}$ (which in your case is the set of recipient sets) and if $\mathsf{P}$ is at least $\epsilon$-secure then $\mathsf{P}$ is also at least $\epsilon\cdot|\mathcal{W}|$-secure. Since the universe $\mathcal{W}$ in the case of private linear broadcast is only of polynomial size, the adaptive security of $\mathsf{P}$ follows.$^*$

I think this idea is folklore, but the earliest formal statement I found goes back to [BB] (Theorem 7.1); you can read more about it in [J+]

[BB] Boneh and Boyen, [Efficient Selective-ID Secure Identity-Based Encryption Without Random Oracles](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/172), Eurocrypt 2004

[J+] Jafargholi et al.,  [Be Adaptive, Avoid Overcommitting](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/515), Crypto 2017

$^*$ In most cases the universe is of exponential size and this lead to an exponential loss in security. But there are examples where this is the best we know!